# Как реализовать скрипт автозапуска/закрытия приложении на Андроиде в определенное время?

Tags: android, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток Дамы и Господа!
Скоординируйте пожалуйста как мне реализовать скрипт для автозапуска выбранных приложении в определенное время каждый день,а после автозакрытия на Андроиде?
Желательно на Python.
Куда двигаться,где искать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Что реализовать? Где реализоваться? Зачем реализовать?

Comment: Непосредственно на смартфоне.